# Forces behind pulling two sheets of glass separated by a thin layer of water

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, water, vacuum, glass

I am currently a high school student in South Korea. I was assigned to conduct a physics research project in school, but I really cannot even get started on solving it and I was wondering if you could help me.

The question is: Investigate the various forces involved when you try to separate two sheets of glass separated by a thin layer of water.

So far, I've found that two main forces will work to make separating the glass harder. First is the fact that you have to break the bonds within the film of water to separate the two sheets, and the second is that sandwiching water between the two sheets creates a pseudo- vacuum which means that air pressure will be pressing down in all directions, and that is what makes separating them harder.

Any and all help will be appreciated. You could basically send me a few key terms to help me get my research started, or send me the name of a research paper, or suggest ways for me to get an experiment designed.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you learn about Surface Tension
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension

and The Laplace Law which gives us the pseudo vacuum pressure you were talking of.
https://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/surten2.html

It is difficult to pull the glass sheets because of the attraction between the molecules of the glass and water as they are adhesive forces. The forces between the water molecules have no effect whatsoever.